# Toggle switch replacement for wet/dry vacuum

Tags: electrical

I have a 10A 250V AC 15A 125V AC collings toggle switch for a shop vac that is broken and discontinued from an older model Rigid vacuum (which works fine but is discontinued). I found  a 8A 250v AC 16A 125v AC switch as replacement.

My shop vac is discontinued but the replacement switch works on newer Rigid vacuums.

Does this seem like it will work?

Thanks

Comment: There are two things to consider - Physical form (does it fit?) and electrical compatibility.  Can you post a picture of the electrical nameplate on the shop vac?  Are you running on 250v or 125v?

Comment: Does it physically fit?  I buy my switches at Mouser or Digi-Key after googling the model numbers etc. on the switch and comparing the physical dimensional drawings.

Comment: It fits in the hole but I’m more concerned about the amp ratings being acceptable. Running on standard house electrical outlet. ?125V